# Content Navigator Open Folder only gets 200 results

Tags: ibm-content-navigator

I'm working on a Response Plugin that sorts the results inside of the folder so that the newest received documents are at the top.

What we have found is that when we have a folder that has more than 200 documents we aren't necessarily getting the newest documents to sort.  We found that our Response filter does intercept and sort what documents it gets from CN, but it seems that it only gets 200, even when the folder contains a total of 400.

We have talked with our content management team and since the 200 results shown, is a corporate setting they aren't willing to up that for performance reasons.

So I'm curious if there is any way to actually get all of the results from a folder so that we can sort them all?

We noticed that even when a column is clicked our filter only gets what CN gives it.

Are we just at the mercy of CN and there isn't a way around upping the results shown or is there something out there I can't find information on?

Thanks!!! Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty annoying problem with the limitation from the central CNav team. 
There is not way to get all the results and show in folder as the restriction is from the admin desktop from where your desktop is created and folder is viewed.

What i would recommend is , get a  new desktop created from the CN admin team and have those feature added if the business unit is small. This will not impact the performane for the overall CN.

I agree we are at mercy of CNav when the customization comes. I am at point in my company to move from thick client for windows to CN and have lot of constraints of what CN can do or not do.

Hope this helps :)